# Add a square box with text using css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a square box using CSS of given size. Then add a paragraph of text inside the square and then center the text horizontally in square.

Here is my code:

```css
#myid {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#myid:after {
  content: 'hello';
}
```

```html
<div id="myid" />
```

The issue is I am able to get the square with text hello centered horizontally but not in the middle of the square.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This might help https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: That's how I solved it I hope that helped.
`#myid {
position: relative;
}  
#myid:after {
content: 'hello';
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%);
left: 50%;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method by far is to use Flexbox. Simple make `#myid` a flex container and center its items:

```css
#myid {
  /* ... */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontally centers */
  align-items: center; /* Vertically centers */
}
```

In addition, you can now remove `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: center`.

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg3u0z4d/.